# How to use cloudinary with mongodb and mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloudinary

I'm trying to save some files in cloudinary(pdf/doc/images) to cloudinary. My controller for getting data from front end and saving one pdf file. I need to save the link to the file to my mongodb database(atlas).

How should I do so? I mean how do I save the link to mongodb atlas and then show to my admin dashboard?

```
const CV                = require('../models/cv.model');
const {cloudinary}      = require('../../../utils/cloudinary');

const addOneCv = async (req, res) => {
    const cv = new CV({
        name: req.body.name,
        contact: req.body.contact,
        email: req.body.email,
        shipType: req.body.shipType,
        rank: req.body.rank,
        cv_file: req.body.cv, // file
        additional_docs: req.body.additional_docs, // file
    })
    try{
        const uploadedResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(cv.cv_file, {
            upload_preset: 'ml_default'
        });
        console.log(uploadedResponse);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    if(cv){
        res.status(200).send({
            data: cv,
            error: "false",
        })
        console.log("cv submitted")
    }else{
        res.status(400).send({
            error: "true",
        })
    }
}
module.exports = {
    addOneCv
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to open support ticket with details of your account of how you are planning to use PDF by going to [their support portal](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new)